# WPF Updating UI using Multiple Classes

Tags: c#, wpf, class, user-interface

I am teaching myself... I cannot understand why the UI won't update when a second class is involved. I am missing something basic and I don't get it.

In the first Class:
I have two ObservableCollections bound to two WPF ListViews, which is bound correctly and works.
I have a Command bound to a Button to move items from one Collection to the other, which works as expected.

In the second Class (backcode) I have implemented "Drag and Drop". On Drop I try to call the same Method (which is in the first Class and is used by the Button/Command. The Command is also in the first class).

On "Drag and Drop" the items are moved from one collection to the other (confirmed with Console.Writeline), however the UI doesn't update like it does with the Button/Command.

I believe the problem is that with "Drag and Drop" I am calling the Method from another class. I thought I could do that, but I must not be doing it right?

I have included everything from 4 files (xaml, backcode, class, relayCommand) so hopefully it is easy to reproduce. Can anyone tell me why & how to get this to work???

```
<Window x:Class="MultipleClassDragAndDrop.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultipleClassDragAndDrop"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MultipleClassDragAndDrop.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="716" Width="500">

<Window.Resources>
    <ViewModel:MultiColumnViewModel x:Key="MultiColumnViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource MultiColumnViewModel}}" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="700"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Content="Test Command" Command="{Binding Test_Command}"/>
        </StackPanel>


        <ListView  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ListView1" Background="Black" MinWidth="165" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveJobListView1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MouseMove="ListView1_MouseMove" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <GroupBox BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"  Width="150" Background="LightPink" BorderBrush="Transparent">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding JobID}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GroupBox>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="700"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <ListView  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ListView2" Background="Black" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="165" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveJobListView2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                   MouseMove="ListView1_MouseMove"
                   AllowDrop="True" Drop="ListView2_Drop" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <GroupBox BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Width="150"  Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="Transparent">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding JobID}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GroupBox>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

BackCode

```
using MultipleClassDragAndDrop.ViewModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MultipleClassDragAndDrop
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MultiColumnViewModel objMultiColumnViewModel = new MultiColumnViewModel();

    private void ListView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            int lb_itemIndex = ListView1.SelectedIndex;

            // Package the data.
            DataObject data = new DataObject();
            data.SetData("Int", lb_itemIndex);
            data.SetData("Object", this);

            // Inititate the drag-and-drop operation.
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }


    private void ListView2_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"\n\n{System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}");

        base.OnDrop(e);

        int index = (int)e.Data.GetData("Int");

        // Call A Method In A Different Class
        objMultiColumnViewModel.AddAndRemove(index);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
}
```

My ViewModel Class

```
using MultipleClassDragAndDrop.ViewModel.Commands;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MultipleClassDragAndDrop.ViewModel
{
public class ActiveJob : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    //INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            Debug.WriteLine($"NOTIFY PROPERTY CHANGED! {info}");
        }

    }
    #endregion

    public string _JobID;
    public string JobID
    {
        get { return _JobID; }
        set
        { _JobID = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("JobID"); }
    }

    public string _CustomerName;
    public string CustomerName
    {
        get { return _CustomerName; }
        set
        { _CustomerName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomerName"); }
    }
}

public partial class MultiColumnViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    //INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            Debug.WriteLine($"NOTIFY PROPERTY CHANGED! {info}");
        }

    }
    #endregion

    //Test Command
    private ICommand _Test_Command;
    public ICommand Test_Command
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Test_Command == null)
            {
                _Test_Command = new RelayCommand<object>(ExecuteTest_Command, CanExecuteTest_Command);
            }

            return _Test_Command;
        }
    }
    public bool CanExecuteTest_Command(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void ExecuteTest_Command(object parameter)
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

        AddAndRemove(0);

        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    public void AddAndRemove(int selectedIndex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"\n\n{System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()} Index = {selectedIndex}\n");

        ActiveJobListView2.Add(ActiveJobListView1[selectedIndex]);

        ActiveJobListView1.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);

        foreach (var item in ActiveJobListView1)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"ActiveJobListView1: {item.JobID}, {item.CustomerName}");
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine($" ");

        foreach (var item in ActiveJobListView2)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"ActiveJobListView2: {item.JobID}, {item.CustomerName}");
        }
    }

    public MultiColumnViewModel()
    {
        ActiveJobListView1 = new ObservableCollection<ActiveJob>();
        ActiveJobListView2 = new ObservableCollection<ActiveJob>();

        ActiveJobListView1.Add(new ActiveJob { JobID = "JOB100", CustomerName = "Smith" });
        ActiveJobListView1.Add(new ActiveJob { JobID = "JOB101", CustomerName = "Jones" });
        ActiveJobListView1.Add(new ActiveJob { JobID = "JOB102", CustomerName = "Black" });
    }

    #region Properties
    private ObservableCollection<ActiveJob> _ActiveJobListView1;
    public ObservableCollection<ActiveJob> ActiveJobListView1
    {
        get { return _ActiveJobListView1; }
        set
        {
            _ActiveJobListView1 = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("ActiveJobListView1");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ActiveJob> _ActiveJobListView2;
    public ObservableCollection<ActiveJob> ActiveJobListView2
    {
        get { return _ActiveJobListView2; }
        set
        {
            _ActiveJobListView2 = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("ActiveJobListView2");
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Comment: Can you point out where the exact problem is ? Which method it works and where it doesn't ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.  The Button/Command works as expected. Items are moved from one ListView to the Other and the UI Listviews are updated correctly. When I "DragDrop" I can see (via Console.Writeline) that Items are moved from one Collection to the other, but the UI does not update the ListViews. note: both use the same Method to move items between Collections, but the UI doesn't update if the Method is called from a different Class.

Comment: I got that part. But can you point that out in the code ?

Comment: The problem is in the "BackCode" I call: // Call A Method In A Different Class
        objMultiColumnViewModel.AddAndRemove(index);    AddAndRemove is the Method that makes the changes to the ObservableCollections.       AddAndRemove is also called from the "ICommand Test_Command", where it works as expected.

Comment: Owki: objMultiColumnViewModel.AddAndRemove(index) does not work ? And where does it work ?

Comment: It does work when called from "ICommand Test_Command" via the bound wpf button.

Comment: Obviously objMultiColumnViewModel.AddAndRemove(index) in your MainWindow is a new instance. That is your main problem

Comment: Is there a way to do it correctly? I kinda get that it's a new instance, but how does one accomplish what I am trying to do, which is call a Method from another class and have it work on the Collections in that class? I can't make the Method static because that causes other problems.

Answer (score 1):

When binding to a Collection, there are 3 kinds of ChangeNotification you need:

1. The Notification that informs the UI if something was added or removed from the Collection. That is the **only** kind of Notification ObservableCollection provides.
2. The Notification on the property exposing the ObservableCollection. Due to case 1 binding and the lack of a "add range", it is a bad idea to do bulk-modifications of a exposed List. Usually you create a new list and only then Expose it to the UI. In your case those would be the properties "ActiveJobListView1" and it's kind.
3. The Notification on every property of every type exposed in the collection. That would be "ActiveJob" in your case.

Some of those are often forgotten, with Case 2 being the most common case. I wrote a small introduction into WPF and the MVVM pattern a few years back. maybe it can help you here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: *"Usually you create a new list and only then expose it to the UI"*. Not *usually*. Imagine a ListBox bound to a collection of 1000 items where you want to replace 100 of them. Replacing the source collection would recreate all items in the ListBox, while removing and adding items to an existing collection would keep 900 items in place. So IMO you would *usually* operate on the existing source collection.

Comment: @Clemens: 1. If you got a 1000 Item collection, something went very wrong to begin with. That is way beyond the amount of Data a User can use. 2. It really depends on how well Virtualsation works. Having 100 changes to a OC can cause a massive amount of overhead due to 100 seperate ChangeNotifications. So big it can be cheaper to re-create the Collection from scratch. At least that way you only have to re-calculate the UI once, not 100 times.

Comment: That just sounds like a lack of real-world UI experience... All I'm saying is that you can't say *usual*. Sometimes one approach is right, sometimes the other.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. My problem specifically seems to be in calling a Method from another Class and the UI failing to Update. I have run into this problem before. Since everything Updates (therefore proven to work) when I call the Method from within the Class, is there a reason why it doesn't Update when I call the same Method from a different class?

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with different instances of the same class.

Change:

```
MultiColumnViewModel objMultiColumnViewModel = new MultiColumnViewModel();
```

To:

```
var objMultiColumnViewModel = this.DataContext as MultiColumnViewModel;
```

and it should work

**EDIT:**

What you are doing is strongly against MVVM principals.

**EDIT-2**

I had to do some modification to you code to make it work:

**In your XAML:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MultiColumnViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

**In your MainWindow.cs:**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        objMultiColumnViewModel = this.DataContext as MultiColumnViewModel;
    }

    private MultiColumnViewModel objMultiColumnViewModel;
```

[image]

Comment: Since you've pointed out that this violates MVVM principles, can you explain how, and provide links to how you might set up something similar while following MVVM principles?
It would be helpful to not only the question-asker, but also to anyone else who later reads this question and answer

Comment: @Zarenor Very simple, simply don't do it. One ViewModel for each View. I can't really see why you wouldn't do both the Drap&Drop and Command in the same ViewModel. But if OP want's that then this is a total different question.

Comment: Thanks. I don't like doing this part with backcode, but I am following the MS: "Walkthrough: Enabling Drag and Drop on a User Control..."   
 When I replaced that line and put yours in (I put it into "ListView2_Drop")  compilation is fine, but I get an error when I try to DragDrop on the line:  DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Move); is highlighted and the error is: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  Which makes no sense to me why I would get that kind of error there.

Comment: I would love to move the backcode to the ViewModel. It would solve a lot of my problems. I intended to try to do that once I got it working. I'm not sure how exactly to do that yet though.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help with this! That is exactly what I was trying to do. I understand the Xaml where the Window gets the DataContext instead of the Grid. So I removed DataContext from my Window.Resources.  I don't understand the two lines added to MainWindow.cs. Could you explain the two lines?

Comment: private MultiColumnViewModel objMultiColumnViewModel; keeps a reference to your ViewModel, in the MainWindow Constructor you set it to the DataContext of the MainWindow, Your DataContext is instanciated from the XAML, therefor you cannot use new MultiColumnViewModel();